# Texture streches on the edge of extruded plane

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv, pixel-art

so I wanted to try and make some 3d models of pixel art, and I started with a basic Minecraft sword to train myself. So I started by adding a plane, adding a texture to it, added loop cuts to my plane, 15 loop cuts because it's a 16x16 texture, then I selected the blank faces and deleted them.

As I extrude this plane, <kbd>A</kbd> > <kbd>E</kbd> > $.1$, the texture messes up on the edge of the item, as shown below

[image]

Although not all faces mess up on the edge, a lot still do. I tried recalculating normals, unwrapping the object again, but I ended with the same problem, no change at all. Though I may have done it wrong, since I never did it before.

**I tried smart UV project and cube projection, but they just mess it up even more.**

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: hello, maybe pack your image and share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: sure! [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=BgQZdmB6" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/BgQZdmB6/)

Comment: thanks but please pack your image before sharing (File > External Data > Pack All Into .blend), save again

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't post the same question more than once. If the linked duplicate in your other question did not address your issue you should edit your original question with more details explaining why so it can be reopened

Comment: What do you mean pack the image? Which image?

Comment: The image you've used called diamond_sword.png, it is not part of your file for the moment, please pack into the file. If I test with another image it seems to work so it would be better to test with your image.

Comment: why would I do that?? I gave you the link to the file

Comment: as I said, I've tested with another image and I can't see any problem, I can't see any messing up on the edges, so it would help to have your image to see the same thing as you

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would just add a UV Seam to both edge rings of the sides, by clicking on the edge ring with Alt + LMB and then adding a seam with U > Mark Seam, and then unwrapping with U > UV-Unwrap. That way you can split the sides from the UV-map which is probably whats causing the weird overlapping!

Comment: that does NOT work. :/

Comment: Sorry to hear that, hope you find a fix soon, I only have limited Blender experience so this was all the advice I could give I'm afraid!

Comment: Thanks anyway !